# header height outside screen components in react native

Tags: react-native

I am having difficulty in determining the height of a header in the headerTitle option of a stackNavigator. when I attempt to use the useHeaderheight hook outside a screen component, it returns a 'Couldn't find the header height. Are you inside a screen in a navigator with a header?' error. Who can suggest a work around please?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the header height using the following method. Note that this is a deprecated method by react-navigation so you will get a warning when using the following, but it works.

```
import { Header } from 'react-navigation';
Header.HEIGHT;
```